# Why do link background and border appear behind the image while the link appears in front?

Tags: css

My "Give Now" and "How You Help" links on the following page are behaving strangely.  They have a background color applied to them, but the color is apparently appearing BEHIND an image while the link appears in front of it.  Thoughts on how to fix this?

http://www.craftonhills.edu/Visitors_and_Friends/Giving_to_CHC/hpr

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
position: relative;
```

to the anchor element within the `foundation-slideshow-prominent-text` `<span>` and the background-color will appear ..

Comment: Bingo. You beat me to it! Nice job

Comment: added this.  Not happening....   .foundation-slideshow-prominent-text a{position:relative}

Comment: line 1120 is the selector to add it to .. maybe your chosing the wrong selector cause it works fine for me in Firefox 15.0.1 and others seemed to agree .. please add it to the line I specified in your screen.css file

Comment: Adding it to .foundation-slide-caption a{} worked.  this is line 1220 in my file...odd.  Thank you.